# Reactivity issue in IE browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

There is data that I receive from the server every 10 seconds in the Vuex repository:

From it I pull the data into the inside of the component through the calculated property:

```
 computed: {

    trackingStatusId: function () {
      return this.$store.state.tracking.trackingServerData.tracking_status_id;
    },
  },
```

Next, I try to work with this data inside the method: And the method itself is attached to the styles in the html block(`<i class="state" :style="getIndicatorWidth()"></i>`)

```
  methods: {

    getIndicatorWidth: function () {

      function widthCalculate(currentTrackingStatusId){

        console.log(currentTrackingStatusId);

      }

      return widthCalculate(this.trackingStatusId);

    },
  },
```

Now we pay attention to this line in the above code:

```
console.log(currentTrackingStatusId);
```

If I get changed data from the server, then the value inside the console log changes reactively in all browsers except IE-11 (and below).

Getting data from the server is as follows:
(hung on a lifecycle hook `mounted ()`)

```
methods: {

    getTrackerIntervalData () {

        setInterval(()=>myTimer(this), 5000);

        function myTimer(th) {
             return axios.get("https://seo-gmbh.eu/couriertracker/json/couriertracker_api.php?action=get_tracking_data&key_id=" + th.$route.params.tracking.toLowerCase() , {
             })
            .then(response => {
              th.$store.commit('tracking/setTrackingServerData', response.data.data.tracking_data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            });
        }
    },
  }
```

Vuex repository:

const axios = require("axios");

```
export const state = () => ({

    trackingServerData: null,

});

export const mutations = {

    setTrackingServerData (state, trackingServerData) {
        state.trackingServerData = trackingServerData;
    },
};
```

I also duplicate the first request from middleware to be able to work with data when rendering a DOM tree:

export default function ({$axios, req, store, route}) {

```
  if(req != undefined) {
      store.commit('setIsFirstServerLoad', true);
  }

  else{
      store.commit('setIsFirstServerLoad', false);
  }

  if(route.name == "language-tracker-tracking") {

      return $axios.get("https://seo-gmbh.eu/couriertracker/json/couriertracker_api.php?action=get_tracking_data&key_id=" + route.params.tracking.toLowerCase(), {})
          .then(response => {
              store.commit('tracking/setTrackingServerData', response.data.data.tracking_data);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
          });

  }

}
```

As a result, if you look at the situation deeper, it turns out that the IE browser correctly calculates only the code received from middleware:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

in the above screenshot, you can observe that the answer 8 - is correct - and the answer 3 is generally not clear where it came from.
(maybe even from the last page from the repository - although I had a separate repository for it there. I have no idea why this happens.)

Question:
Why data is not updated correctly in IE browsers? 
How can this be fixed or is it possible to get around this problem - to implement everything differently?

Comment: Can you confirm that your component does indeed re-render when your data updates and the log message is coming from widthCalculate ? From my understanding of Vue it should be a static value after it initially renders ( and not re-render)

Comment: Yes I can.
http://joxi.ru/GrqlZnXCkwXDeA
here it is in the firefox browser.
All works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here

```
getTrackerIntervalData () {

        setInterval(()=>myTimer(this), 5000);

        function myTimer(th) {
             return axios.get("https://seo-gmbh.eu/couriertracker/json/couriertracker_api.php?action=get_tracking_data&key_id=" + th.$route.params.tracking.toLowerCase() , {
             })
            .then(response => {
              th.$store.commit('tracking/setTrackingServerData', response.data.data.tracking_data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
```

**IE dosent support arrow function.**
you should do it like so

```
getTrackerIntervalData () {
let vm=this;
        setInterval(function(){myTimer(vm)}, 5000);

        function myTimer(th) {
             return axios.get("https://seo-gmbh.eu/couriertracker/json/couriertracker_api.php?action=get_tracking_data&key_id=" + th.$route.params.tracking.toLowerCase() , {
             })
            .then(response => {
              th.$store.commit('tracking/setTrackingServerData', response.data.data.tracking_data);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
```

because vue use webpack. normally arrow function will be transform to normal function to support all browsers but maybe for some reason the `setInterval` with arrow function not transform. try it maybe that the problem

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help (
That is not working.
I have the same problem.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/Y2LlMPYCQbyq82
The problem with the IE browser is here.
I don't know why..
the date does not update in that place.

Comment: nuxt will transform arrow functions so its not an issue